# How do I install solr-jetty 3.4.0?

Tags: 11.10, package-management

Does anyone know of a package which install `solr-jetty` with Solr version 3.4.0 on Oneiric (11.10)?

The [official `solr-jetty` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/solr-jetty) has Solr version 1.4.1, which isn't up-to-date (for my uses).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This Solr package has been orphaned, but someone intends to maintain it. Please see bug number [#652729](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=652729) for more information.

The latest version of Solr is 3.5.0, Fortunately, I published solr packages for Ubuntu Oneiric to [my own PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gasol-wu/+archive/oneiric) repository last week, You can easily add source repository and install package as following instructions:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gasol-wu/oneiric`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install solr-jetty`

then open your browser go to **'http://localhost:8080/solr'**, you will see what you want.